# NHibernate support the function: LEN

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I want to get the results:

```
select * from Cate where LEN(code)=2
```

My code:

```
var filter1 = Restrictions.Eq(
                 Projections.SqlFunction("LEN", NHibernateUtil.Int32,
                                         Projections.Property("code")), 2);
             var query =
                 repository.Session.QueryOver<Cate>().Where(filter1).List();
             Assert.IsTrue(query.Count > 0);
```

However, there have been errors:

> NHibernate.HibernateException : Current dialect
>   NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect doesn't support the function: LEN

How can I use in Nhibernate the SQLServer2008 of the Len function?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should register your function either in the Configuration class

```
config.AddSqlFunction("len", new StandardSafeSQLFunction("len", NHibernateUtil.Int32, 1));
```

or to create a custom dialect

```
public class MyDialect : MsSql2008Dialect
{
    public MyDialect()
    {
        RegisterFunction("len", new StandardSafeSQLFunction("len", NHibernateUtil.Int32, 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `length` instead of `len`. That's how it's registered in the dialect.