# NHibernate QueryOver restrict by string length

Tags: nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-criteria

How do I restrict a query by the length of a string property? eg. something like:

```
NHSession.QueryOver<Customer>()
    .Where(p => p.RegistryCode.Length == 8)
```

Comment: It would be nice if you add a few more details to your question.

Comment: Don't know what additional detail I could add, it seems a pretty straightforward question to me?

Comment: yes your question is not too heavy ;-) - but it contains things like `customer` and a constant (e.g. `8`), which are not further explained. Don't worry it's ok as it is AND you got your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this may do the trick

```
NHSession.QueryOver<Customer>()
    .Where(
        Restrictions.Eq(
            Projections.SqlFunction("length", NHibernateUtil.String, 
                Projections.Property<Customer>(x => x.RegistryCode)),
            8
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, worked, although I had to use "length" instead of "len", as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246626/nhibernate-support-the-function-len)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "NHibernateUtil.String" i should use this "NHibernateUtil.Int16" type, because a 'length' parameter should always be a number and not a String.

Something like this:

```
NHSession.QueryOver<Customer>()
    .Where(
        Restrictions.Eq(
            Projections.SqlFunction("length", NHibernateUtil.Int16, 
                Projections.Property<Customer>(x => x.RegistryCode)),
            8
        )
    )
```

Comment: Why should this be better? Please explain.

Comment: In my opinion, a length return a int not a string. But it's a nhibernate sql action it does not really matter.